# Any free or capable software able to load SF2 soundbank and listen to MIDI Input port?

Tags: windows

I been trying to get FluidSynth 1.1.1 to work with winmidi command and load a sf2 soundbank, it doesn't seem to capture MIDI file or MIDI event that play through LoopBe1 virtual MIDI driver.

Have anyone tried before?